# Wth rails 6 and postgresql, return a object collection using an array item as references

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

Using Rail 6 and postgres, I need to generate a collection of objects, using the item array on field *relations*, returning all person 'duplicated' with the relation he has.

The database field has created with this migration:

```
t.integer :relations, array: true, null: false, default: []
...
add_index :people, :relations, using: :gin
```

And it created this table:

```
id | name |  relations  |
------------------------|
 1 | João | {nil,1,2,3} |
 2 | Maria| {nil,1}     |
```

I need a return like this, without *nil*;

```
[
  {id: 1, name: 'João', relation: 1},
  {id: 1, name: 'João', relation: 2},
  {id: 1, name: 'João', relation: 3},
  {id: 2, name: 'Maria', relation: 1}
]
```

Something like that poor sql:

```
SELECT id, name, '1' as relation FROM people WHERE 1 = ANY (relations)
union
SELECT id, name, '2' as relation FROM people WHERE 2 = ANY (relations)
union
SELECT id, name, '3' as relation FROM people WHERE 3 = ANY (relations);
```

tks :)

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the expected result:

```
Person.joins(", unnest(people.relations) rel")
      .where("rel is not null")
      .select("people.id, people.name, rel")
```

(For Postgres version > 9.4)